# Trouble retrieving PFusers from parse.com for an IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, appdelegate

I am building an IOS app in swift 2.0 in xCode Beta. I built a custom user class which subclasses PFUser, relevant excerpts of the class are reproduced below

```
import UIKit

class User: PFUser, Entity {
    // MARK: - Declare Field Variables
    @NSManaged var firstName : String
    @NSManaged var lastName : String
    //Several other state variables follow in the same format

    ///initializing a new person
    init (firstName: String, lastName: String, password: String, email: String) {
        super.init()
        super.username = email
        super.password = password
        super.email = email
        //set initial key-value pairs for person
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

        // Special method to sign up new user
        super.signUp()
    }
    // Additional methods placed here

    // MARK: - Conformation to PFObjectSubclassing
    override class func initialize() {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }

    // MARK: - Conformation to Entity
    func saveToDatabase() {
        //Saves the new PFObject Asyncronously
        self.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success)    { print("User \(self.username) succesfully saved to database.") }
            else            { print(error) }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the parse GUI, I verified that Users were successfully saved to the database.

I am attempting to retrieve the data using a class written in the Appdelegate, that is called from the Appdelegate as follows:

```
var examplePerson: User!

func funcThatIsCalled() {
    var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    var people = query.findObjects()
    self.examplePerson = people![0] as! User
}
```

This returns the error:

"Could not cast value of type 'PFUser' (0x108326490) to 'MyPersonalApp.User' (0x108323f80)."

Adding User.registerSublass() to the Appdelegate as follows:

```
User.registerSubclass()
        // Initialize Parse.
        Parse.setApplicationId("myAppID",
            clientKey: "MyClientKey")
```

results in the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The class PFUser must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse.'

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
PFUser.query()
```

should be

```
User.query()
```